# Super Navbar in Webview

Tags: user-interface, uinavigationbar, navbar, appgyver

So I have a basic webview app, works perfectly. I have a link from one of my webpages. However, the issue is that my top navigation bar does not show.

In android, we simply add it to the xml file before webview. How  to achieve this in AppGyver?

Answer (score 0):

So even after searching a lot and trying to get to appgyver, I could not get a solution so found a work around.

I created a top bar using ionic and added to my app simply. This makes any transition looks like previous with a slight load time difference but is workable. I still would  prefer a more "native" solution.